# Trying to change header background after scrolling to a certain point

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the background color of my header to red when I scroll past a certain point. I have this code:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop >= document.getElementById("invisible").offsetTop) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    navbar.classList.add("red");
  } 
  else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    navbar.classList.remove("red");
  }
}
```

The sticky part works so when I scroll past a certain point the the header sticks to the top. And in the inspect element the header also gets `background-color: red;` after I scroll past the point but the header stays transparant. Why?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
html:

```
<header id="navbar">
        <img class="rocket" src="img/rocket.png"/>
        <div class="title">&nbsp;&nbsp;Title</div>
        <nav class="nav">
            <a href="#home" class="navItem1"><img class="homeimg" src="img/home.png">Home</img></a>
            <a href="#faq" class="navItem2"><img class="faqimg" src="img/faq.png">FAQ</img></a>
            <a href="#contact" class="navItem3"><img class="contactimg" src="img/phone.png">Contact</img></a>
            <a href="#tips&tricks" class="navItem4"><img class="tipstricksimg" src="img/bulb.png">Tips & Tricks</img></a>
            <a href="#gereedschappen&modellen" class="navItem5"><img class="modelsimg" src="img/wrench.png">Gereedschappen & Modellen</img></a>
        </nav>
</header>
<div class="invisible" id="invisible"></div>
```

css:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you also provide styles and html?

Comment: Need to see your styles to answer the question

Comment: @izmaylovdev sorry about that, edited

Comment: @Daniel_Knights sorry about that, edited

Comment: Just tried it here and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/o7a396Lz/

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Any idea why it's not working for me? https://gyazo.com/c686cae6f13fe0569f5fa97ab3622188

Comment: No idea. Could you make a code pen for me to have a look at?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Can't seem to replicate the problem, in codepen it works aswell https://codepen.io/TijnvA/pen/JjGJoXv